# Rails using remote: true to control popup

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, helper

Say I have an object `s` defined by the `Student` model. This object has many properties, including a related `scores` object. Inside the `show` view relevant for `s`, there's a button which opens up this student's `scores` view in a new window using `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to t("s.show_scores"), show_scores_path(s: s.id), method: :get, 'data-popup' => true, form: {class: 'button-up'} -%>
```

Now, there's a situation where a student hasn't got all his scores yet, in which I don't want the `scores` view to open. This is done using a conditional in the controller: Checking `@s.scores.valid?`, if so then proceed, otherwise instead of showing the `scores` view, it opens a popup window with the current view and an alert message I've made:

```
def show_scores
    @s = Student.find(params[:student])
    @s.calc_response_scores_if_missing
    if(@s.scores.valid?)
        redirect_to students_path, flash: {alert: I18n.t("students.missing_obs")} and return
    end
    @format = "html"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
```

I want to take it a step further: I want that upon clicking the button, the `@s.scores.valid?` condition will be checked. If positive then proceed to opening the view in a popup, if negative I want no popup window opened and the alert to appear on the current page (obviously using `render` instead of `redirect_to`). I think this can be done using `remote: true` but I'm not quite sure how. Any assistance would be great :)

Comment: Yes, that can be done by using `ajax`. Also, you can just add the condition `if-else` in your view and when `@s.scores.valid?` render `button_to t("s.show_scores"), show_scores_path(s: s.id) ...`, else render not linked button that has the same name and that just display your message on click via js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could already do this upon the first load of the show view. Based on the conditional you render the button that triggers the right user experience. So in pseudo code:

show.html.erb

```
<%=
@s.scores.valid? ? "render button that opens popup" : "render button that does something else"
%>
```

Comment: This asks me to put logic inside the view, which I try to avoid. Also I like this button to be displayed at all times.

Comment: It will display at all times, only the functionality it triggers could be different. You could use a special class so you can catch the click via JS. Also, nothing wrong with some logic in the view. You could always refactor it out by using a ViewPresentor or something: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way you can do without using ajax (`remote: true`) is rendering the popup with "Score not valid" message and a button to close the window, or just render the blank page with a javascript code to close the window instantly (Facebook use this kind of technique with their login button.)

```
<script>
  window.close();
</script>
```

I wouldn't recommend the popup way though, you can use ajax to re-render the view partial, or open the jQuery (or whatever js library you're using) popup for instance.